# PostGis st_dwithin super slow when inserting

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-dwithin, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to insert the newly obtained data from st_dwithin into a new table.

However, it has been running since 1 day and I still can't get any data into the new table.

Can i know what is the problem?

When i do the select only, it took less than 10 seconds to return the result

```
sql> SELECT
            a.event_id,
            a.local_date,
            a.source,
            a.user_id,
            a.tourism_region_name,
            a.latitude,
            a.longitude,
            b.poi_latitude,
            b.poi_longitude,
            b.name,
            b.zip_code,
            b.city,
            b.group_designation,
            b.category_id,
            a.geom,
            b.geom
    FROM attraction_dwell_pre_2 a left JOIN tomo_poi_master_rto_sub2 b
        ON ST_DWithin(a.geog, b.geog, 200.00)
```

**[2018-01-17 12:40:14] 500 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 792ms (execution: 621ms, fetching: 171ms)**

Below is my code:

```
create table attraction_dwell_pre_3 as
(
   SELECT
            a.event_id,
            a.local_date,
            a.source,
            a.user_id,
            a.tourism_region_name,
            a.latitude,
            a.longitude,
            b.poi_latitude,
            b.poi_longitude,
            b.name,
            b.zip_code,
            b.city,
            b.group_designation,
            b.category_id,
            a.geom,
            b.geom
    FROM attraction_dwell_pre_2 a LEFT JOIN tomo_poi_master_rto_sub2 b
        ON ST_DWithin(a.geog, b.geog, 200.00)
);
```

*There are no index or primary key on the 2 tables

Comment: ST_DWithin doesn't insert features, so your question title needs to be edited. As with all SQL optimization requests, we need the table definitions, the spatial references, and an EXPLAIN plan for your statement. You should **always** build a spatial index before querying.

Comment: Hi @Vince, should i build spatial index on both table's geography/geometry column or only on 1 table?

Comment: @Derek on both tables, then you should cluster by it.

Comment: You might need to build *multiple* indexes on the same column, if you need a geodetic spatial search on a geometry column. But that's not what's causing a day of delay when creating a table based on a 10-second query.

Comment: Technically you only need an index on tomo_poi_master_rto_sub2, as you are doing a LEFT JOIN, which will necesitate a full table scan of attraction_dwell_pre_2 anyway. However, as a general rule, you should pretty much always put a spatial index on any geometry column. If you run EXPLAIN on your query, with or without indexes, you should see the difference.